# How I can share my application docker image or container without code access to others

Tags: docker, dockerhub, docker-image

I have executed a dockerfile and built a docker image.

But I want to provide this image to run at third party end without code access.code should not be visible to them.

How I can i acheve this with docker any idea?

Comment: Then you is not sharing there is something call GNU. All you can do is add a copyright notice which honestly everyone removes

Comment: @Ernesto Didn't get what actually you mean to say. could you please explain?

Comment: No you can not GNU is an open source organization.

Comment: Now I see where this question came from

Comment: That depends. What kind of code are we talking about?

Comment: I have python flask application.

Comment: You need to use a compiled language (Go, Rust, C++) that would let you distribute the application without its source.  It's very easy to see what's inside a Docker image and extract it, and basically impossible to protect it.

Comment: For a Python app, you could also look into e.g. Nuitka...